# How to concatenate corresponding lines in two text files

Tags: powershell, batch-file, concatenation

I have two text files that I need to combine by concatenating line n from file #2 to line n of file #1 to make line n of file #3.  They will always have the same number of lines and will always match up (i.e. line 1 in one file is a match to line 1 in the second file).  I have to concatenate these two files into a new, third file.  No spaces added between the fields. I am running Windows 7 and using a batch file but I could use powershell if that’s a better choice here. Here's an example of the first file named test.txt:

```
13CT162| 
13MM1364 VOP AFF| 
13MM1872| 
14ct70| 
Another| 
brake f_Page_1|
brake f_Page_2| 
brake f_Page_3| 
brake f_Page_4| 
brake f_Page_5|
```

Here's the corresponding info  from the second file named Index1.txt:

```
\\TEST-CLER\COMPLETE\13CT162.tif
\\TEST-CLER\COMPLETE\13MM1364 VOP AFF.tif
\\TEST-CLER\COMPLETE\13MM1872.tif
\\TEST-CLER\COMPLETE\14ct70.tif
\\TEST-CLER\COMPLETE\Another.tif
\\TEST-CLER\COMPLETE\brake f_Page_1.tif
\\TEST-CLER\COMPLETE\brake f_Page_2.tif
\\TEST-CLER\COMPLETE\brake f_Page_3.tif

\\TEST-CLER\COMPLETE\brake f_Page_4.tif
\\TEST-CLER\COMPLETE\brake f_Page_5.tif
```

I need the new file to look like this (line 1):

```
13CT162|\\TEST-CLER\COMPLETE\13CT162.tif
```

I can find lots of help on how to append the files but little on how to concatenate two files into a third one. There is an existing answer here but it is for Python. I have to use Win 7 cmd or powershell commands. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a For loop to do this in PowerShell:

```
$File1 = Get-Content C:\Path\To\File1.txt
$File2 = Get-Content C:\Path\To\File2.txt
$File3 = @()
For($a=0;$a -lt $File1.count;$a++){
    $File3+=$File1[$a].trim()+$File2[$a].trim()
}
$File3 | Out-File C:\Path\To\NewFile.txt
```

**Edit:** Ok, I didn't think of single line files. That would make $File1 and/or $File2 strings instead of arrays. We can make them arrays easily enough so it can properly index into them:

```
$File1 = @((Get-Content C:\Path\To\File1.txt))
$File2 = @((Get-Content C:\Path\To\File2.txt))
$File3 = @()
For($a=0;$a -lt $File1.count;$a++){
    $File3+=$File1[$a].trim()+$File2[$a].trim()
}
$File3 | Out-File C:\Path\To\NewFile.txt
```

Comment: Hey my boss just pointed out an issue with this script - if the files being concatenated are just one line - then nothing is written to the  new file.  What switch is it that tells PS to make a file even when file1 and file2 have only one line & no carriage return? Do I need to make a carriage return in the original files?

Comment: You're right, try the edit and that should fix it. It's because single line files get read in as a string instead of an array. I forced them into being an array with the edit, so it can index into them properly now.

Comment: Wait, I'm sorry it's a Friday afternoon...am brain dead. So add a CRLF to both files?  THese files are dynamically generated by another script - when the script generates them and there is only one line, my part of the task fails.  I don't know how to add to the txt file if it's generated by another script.

Comment: No, the edited code in my answer should work on single line files (as well as multi-line files, just as before)

Comment: Oh  forgive me. I was typing your instructions wrong. Jeez, you have completely saved me on this job...thank you so much!  Good Karma to you, sir

Comment: If my index files have more than one line, it fails.  What have I done wrong?

Comment: Bah, that was creating nested arrays. Try the update. Sorry, not trying to make this difficult. I tested with both single and multi-line files and it worked for me.

Comment: Hmm, I should have hit the refresh on this page - will try your suggestion now. Thank you!!!