# Merge two text files

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-7, notepad++

I'm using Windows and Notepad++ to separate file in txt. I have 2 files which is I have to merge it side by side or line by line for my data analysis.

Here is the example:

file1.txt

```
Abcdefghijk
abcdefghijk
```

file2.txt

```
123456
123456
```

then the output I want is like this:

```
Abcdefghijk123456
abcdefghijk123456
```

in the next file or output file. Does anybody here know how to do this?

Comment: Check the below link. Hope it might help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/24404352/2244720

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge 2 text files into one, same lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24403885/merge-2-text-files-into-one-same-lines)

Answer (score 0):

Your question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25392930/4374644) by [TheMadTechnician](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3245749/themadtechnician). Using powershell, you should take both source files (1 and 2) as arrays of lines. Then comes simple cycle, like "merge line x from file1 with line x from file2 as long you have some lines in file1".
Unfortunately its impossible with pure cmd.

Comment: is that possible if i have 2million lines ?

Comment: Why not? At least, C# equivalent of this powershell code will surely do it (sometimes powershell have some problems with big numbers like xmillions, so I'm not 100% sure about it. But you can simply try :) )

Answer (score 0):

@riki.. you could also write a batch program to do this pro grammatically. There should probably be no limit over the number of lines.

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on the number of lines you're having in each files. I suggest to copy paste the same if it is less than 50 lines. 
Otherwise, 
use some powerful languages like python, c,php etc. And make it run before performing data analysis.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free utility you can download and run on your computer, called **txtcollector**.  I read about it [here](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/combine-or-merge-all-text-files-with-txtcollector/).  I used it because I had a whole folder of files to concatenate.  It was a breeze.  The only slight imperfection I noticed was that I couldn't paste in the path to the specific folder in the first step (choosing the folder where the files to be concatenated were).  However, I could do this when choosing where to save the result.