# Merge two text line-by-line with for each text file in directory

Tags: php, powershell, batch-file

I learned to merge only 2 files in [php](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24403964/7947164) or [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25392930/7947164). But I could not do for every file in a folder.

I've thousands of files like this. I simplified the contents to give an example:

*"Working directory"*
Title 1 (a).txt
Title 1 (b).txt
Title 2 (a).txt
Title 2 (b).txt
Title 3 (a).txt
Title 3 (b).txt
Title ... (a).txt
Title ... (b).txt

*Contents of "Title 1 (a).txt"*

```
Apple
Lettuce
Life
```

*Contents of "Title 1 (b).txt"*

```
a fruid
a vegetable
a movie
```

---

I would like the output file:
***"Title 1.txt"***

```
Apple is a fruid
Lettuce is a vegetable
Life is a movie
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You are much more likely to receive a response if you show what you have tried and where you are running into issues rather than looking for someone to write a solution for you. If you use PowerShell, some starting points would be the `Get-ChildItem`, `Group-Object`, `Get-Content`, and `ForEach-Object` cmdlets. You can get information on these with `Get-Help xxxx -Full` where `xxxx` is the name of the cmdlet

Comment: Thank you @BenH. I'm glad to be here. I'm really a beginner. I know only for loop in cmd, I tried for hours but erased what I've tried. I could not put it together.

Comment: It would help if you provided that which you've admitted learning when merging two files in the two languages you've also tagged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do it in PowerShell:

```
#Get the all the files in the folder
$Files = Get-ChildItem C:\ExamplePath -File
#Use a ForEach loop to get just the titles, split on ( and trim the extra space
$FileTitles = ForEach ($File in $Files ) {
    ($file.basename.split("("))[0].trim()
}
#Group the titles (Select-Object -unique would also work here)
$GroupedTitles = ($FileTitles | Group-Object).Name
#Loop over each group
ForEach ($Title in $GroupedTitles) {
    #Filter down to just the two files matching the title
    $ToJoin = $Files | Where-Object {$_.basename -like "$Title*"}
    #From TheMadTechnician answer with extra space between the joined lines
    $File1 = Get-Content $ToJoin[0].Fullname
    $File2 = Get-Content $ToJoin[1].Fullname
    $File3 = @()

    For($a=0;$a -lt $File1.count;$a++){
        $File3+=$File1[$a].trim() + " " +$File2[$a].trim()
    }
    #Create the output path using a subexpression $() so that a variable property can be evaluated inside of double quotes
    $File3 | Out-File "$($ToJoin[0].Directory.fullname)\$Title.txt" 
}
```

Comment: Dear @BenH I've tested it in thousands of files. The result is perfect. Thank you for being patient and helping it improve. Inline comments are excellent.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Process all files that ends in " (a).txt" from current folder
for %%a in ("* (a).txt") do (
   set "name=%%~Na"

   rem Read file A from redirected Stdin
   < "%%a" (

      rem Read file B via a FOR /F command
      for /F "usebackq delims=" %%b in ("!name:~0,-4! (b).txt") do (

         rem For each line in file B, read a line from file A
         set /P "lineA="

         rem Echo both input lines in same line...
         echo !lineA! %%b
      )
   rem ... into the output file
   ) > "!name~0,-4!.txt"

   rem Optional: remove both input files
   REM del "%%a" "!name:~0,-4! (b).txt"
)
```

This program have not any error checking in order to made it simpler...

Answer (score 0):

Although you did not show any own efforts, I want to provide pure [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) solutions, because the task at hand is not that trivial.

---

In the following code, the file `* (a).txt` of a pair is read by a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) and `* (b).txt` is read by [input redirection `<`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

for %%F in (".\* (a).txt") do (
    set "FLOC=%%~dpF"
    set "FEXT=%%~xF"
    set "NAME=%%~nF"
    set "FILE1=%%~F"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "NAME=!NAME:~,-4!"
    set "FILE2=!FLOC!!NAME! (b)!FEXT!"
    if exist "!FILE2!" (
        if not exist "!FLOC!!NAME!!FEXT!" (
            > "!FLOC!!NAME!!FEXT!" (
                for /F "delims= eol=|" %%E in ("!FILE2!") do (
                    for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("!FILE1!") do (
                        endlocal
                        set "LINE1=%%L"
                        set "LINE2=" & < "%%E" set /P LINE2=""
                        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                        echo(!LINE1! is !LINE2!
                    )
                )
            )
        ) else (
            >&2 echo ERROR: File "!FLOC!!NAME!!FEXT!" already exists^^!
        )
    ) else (
        >&2 echo ERROR: File "!FILE2!" cannot be found^^!
    )
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

---

In the following code, both files `* (a).txt` and `* (b).txt` of a pair are read by [input redirection `<`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

for %%F in (".\* (a).txt") do (
    set "FLOC=%%~dpF"
    set "FEXT=%%~xF"
    set "NAME=%%~nF"
    set "FILE1=%%~F"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "NAME=!NAME:~,-4!"
    set "FILE2=!FLOC!!NAME! (b)!FEXT!"
    if exist "!FILE2!" (
        if not exist "!FLOC!!NAME!!FEXT!" (
            for /F %%N in ('^< "!FILE1!" find /C /V ""') do set "NUM=%%N"
            9< "!FILE1!" 8< "!FILE2!" > "!FLOC!!NAME!!FEXT!" (
                for /L %%I in (1,1,!NUM!) do (
                    set "LINE1=" & <&9 set /P LINE1=""
                    set "LINE2=" & <&8 set /P LINE2=""
                    echo(!LINE1! is !LINE2!
                )
            )
        ) else (
            >&2 echo ERROR: File "!FLOC!!NAME!!FEXT!" already exists^^!
        )
    ) else (
        >&2 echo ERROR: File "!FILE2!" cannot be found^^!
    )
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you for batch-file solutions. Everyone should see this too. It may even be more extensive. Actually the filenames are more complicated, not like my simplified example, ie they're not ordered (a) and (b) regularly. I will try to improve your codes a little bit. If I match in the odd-numbered and even-numbered files in the list it would be great.

Comment: You're welcome! So you should have posted how your files are actually named. Anyway, You can experiment around and if stuck, you can ask another question, given that you show your attempts and provide real example data...